# HTML5 video - overlay a div above it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, video

So I have the following code:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="video-container">
        <video controls="true" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" preload="auto">
            <source src="/videos/bg-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="/videos/bg-video.ogv" type="video/ogv">
            Please upgrade your browser so that it supports HTML5 videos.
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="text"><!-- ... --></div>
</div>
```

And that's the CSS:

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}

.video-container {
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

video {
    z-index: -1;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

So the `.text` div serves as the actual content of the page. It is a div in the middle of the page and the video appears as a background behind it. So here's the problem:
When I right click on the video I can see options such as unmute, full screen, pause, play speed, show/hide controls/stats, view/copy video, save, share email video. That's why I added the `z-index: -1;` on the `.video-container`. But now I can't select any text in my `.text` div?! That's really frustraiting... I added the `javascript`/`jquery` tag in case there's a JS solution. However I'd rather accept a markup/css solution because JS can be disabled at any time by the user...

Comment: Do you have a fiddle? Have you tried .text { z-index: 99; position: relative; }

Comment: Hey, now that was great! I never thought of that. You can add this as an answer because it worked!

Comment: looks like you got an answer as I was typing mine, but check out a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nickpish/kLszq509/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When z-indexing an element you need to make sure to z-index the other elements your are layering as well.

```
.text{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
}
```